# ¿Por qué al mandar UPDATE no actualiza los datos de mi base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

No me manda ningún mensaje de error ni nada, si no fuera por el if del final parecería que los datos se actualizan, pero no sé qué puede estar mal.

Este es el código:

```
<?php   
require("../php/conexion.php");

$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$id_usuario=$_POST['id'];

$sql2= "SELECT * FROM color";
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2);

$sql3= "SELECT * FROM contenedor";
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql3);

if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            if ($row['tipo'] == $tipo) {
                $color = $row['color'];
            }
        }   
    }
if($resultado2->num_rows > 0){
    while($row2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()){
        if ($row2['id_usuario'] == $id_usuario) {
            $id = $row2['id'];;
        }
    }   
}

$sql= mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE contenedor SET id_usuario = ".$id_usuario.", tipo=".$tipo.", color = ".$color.",
                    WHERE id='$id'");
    //echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Datos Actualizados Exitosamente");</script> ';
    //  echo ' <script language="javascript">location="../perfil.php?id=$_SESSION[id]";</script> ';
if ($sql) {
        echo $color;
                        echo $id;
                        echo $tipo;
    }else{
        echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("error");</script> ';
    }       ?>
```

Solo si es necesario pongo una imagen de mi base de datos: **contenedor**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomendaría que el código fuera en texto y no en imagen. Podrías editar tu pregunta

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: soy nuevo, disculpen por los fallos, acabo de ponerlo como código.

Comment: Bueno tu codigo parece corecto.. te fijaste que estes recibiendo los parametros que vos queres actualizar? que son esos dos select antes del update?

Comment: Si revise los parámetros y todos los recibo.
Los dos select los estoy usando para recibir los datos de otras tablas, bueno según el tutorial que revise era una forma de llamar datos de otras tablas

Comment: si pero esos otros datos (si fueran mas de uno) , lo guardas en una variable sola.. no en muchas variables.. con lo cual, si todo funciona, solo estas actualizando una fila y solo la ultima que recorres.. e igual, suena raro que busques datos en otras tablas que ya vienen de la pantalla... no se porque no te funciona, pero probar hacer un echo de tu query, a ver si vienen todo correcto...

Comment: acabo de por como dijiste, ise un echo con estos 3:  **echo $color; echo $id; echo $tipo;** y los datos vinieron correctos

Comment: Porque me parece que antes del Where hay una `,`  demas

Comment: Conviene siempre dar una breve explicación del contexto y de lo que quieres hacer para poder ayudarte mejor. En este caso no es necesario hacer dos consultas SELECT para luego tomar los datos y hacer un UPDATE. Todo se puede hacer en una sola consulta.